# SqlDataSource not populating controls until after page_load

Tags: binding, controls, sqldatasource

bit new to asp.net so bear with me. I have a dropdown that is being populated from a SqlDataSource. This dropdown's selected value is used as a parameter in another SqlDataSource for my results grid.

Problem is my dropdown is not being populated with anything until after page_load. This is causing an issue because I'm calling a method that uses the dependent SqlDataSource in the page_load, and it blows up because one of its parameters is null.

I've tried the page_prerender as well, and the drop down is still not populated by then. Any ideas on what method in the life cycle I can use, or a way to populate the SqlDataSource controls earlier?

Comment: You shoud try something like this: if the param is null, then populate the grid with all the data ;)

Comment: unfortunately I really need this parameter. I'm using it to populate the intial grid for a given "product"..which is the parameter. Then i'm using the dates in the grid to populate 2 drop downs, start and end year.

So the way it works is, calls the gridview datasource with no start and end dates, and gets all the items in the table for that "product", then the method does some linq on all the dates in the results set and then populates those in start and end date dropdown. Then the user can use those to narrow the search results.